# How to test asymmetry?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a series and I need to check if the values are asymmetric or not (less or more) with respect to the mean.

What test should I use?

Comment: Is the mean a known value or is it to be estimated from the sample? Also, is this a time series with the possibility of serial correlation?

Comment: @Ming-ChihKao, THose values are the residuals of a linear regression, are indipendent(random). The mean is unknown

Comment: If the regression includes a constant, the mean residual is guaranteed to be zero.  Normally one doesn't formally test residuals for symmetry: the purpose is usually exploratory or diagnostic or both.  It's straightforward to check with a folded histogram or an m-letter summary.  For additional suggestions see [EDA short course part 1](http://www.datavis.ca/courses/eda/eda1.html).

Comment: @whuber what do you think about Jarque Bera test? should it be useful for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The measure to use for testing asymmetry is something like the [sample skewness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness). For the purpose of testing, you can just take the numerator $S=1/n \sum(x_i-\bar{x})^3$. Do this for your sample for the observed $S$.

As you can see for a symmetric distribution, $S$ is expected to be $0$.

Once we have a measure sensitive to distributional asymmetry, we need to have a sense of whether your observed $S$ is statistically significantly different from the null hypothesis value of $0$.

To generate the sampling distribution, you could use bootstrap and re-sample your data say $500$ times, calculate $S$ for each, and generate a distribution.

Use the bootstrapped value distribution to test it against it containing $0$, this would necessarily be a single-tailed test.

Comment: thank you! one question...maybe Jarque Bera test should be useful to check asymmetry?

Comment: I was going to propose first testing the residuals for normality, then testing the skewness vs 0 against the sampling distribution from a normal, or against pre-defined critical values (btw Jarque Bera is new to me, thanks!). But most critical values depend on having large samples for the theory to kick in. Hence the preference for bootstrap here and in general.

Comment: I think http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarque%E2%80%93Bera_test should do all the "checks" you told, could you see it and give me an opinion? thank you very much

Comment: As defined, the JB test statistic is compared against a chi-square test of 2 df. The test depends on the assumption of normality, which you would have to test for in a preparatory step. Sample size does appear to be an issue: according to the wiki page, "for small samples the chi-square approximation is overly sensitive".

Comment: @Ming-ChikKao I think is not a problem because the size of the sample is 800 (800 values) so I don't think it is small for this purpose, no? Ok, so I can use Jarque as "second" test, What do you think about Anderson-Darling test for normality as first step?

Comment: That is true, with 800 you can expect good behavior of the JB and the AD tests. The question of using JB+AD versus bootstrap is a question of approach. In this age of cheap computational power, I'm personally more in favor of going with bootstrap. One thing to note, if the AD test comes back rejecting normality, then we'll probably go back tobootstrap anyway.

Comment: OK perfect! Make sense...  I also have seen Wilcoxon signed-rank. It checks the median, but If you take a look at the "Assumptions" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) you will see "Each Zi comes from the same continuous population, and is symmetric about a common median θ ." it should mean that if this test FAIL probably the residuals are not symmetric, wrong?